# How to iterate over Presto ARRAY(MAP(VARCHAR, VARCHAR))

Tags: arrays, lambda, presto

I have an array of maps (unordered key-value pairs), and would like to filter out any map items in the array that do not have either a created or a modified date before 2019-01-01. Is there a way to accomplish this in presto without nested tables (I have to iterate over multiple columns that are structured in this way)?

BEFORE

```
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+--+
| Category1 | Count_Items | Item_Details                                                                                                                                               |  |  |
+===========+=============+============================================================================================================================================================+==+==+
| Fruit     | 3           | [{"created":"2019-09-15","color":"red","name":"apples"},{"name":"bananas","created":"2018-08-20"},{"modified":"2019-02-01","name":"kiwi","color":"green"}] |  |  |
| Vegetable | 2           | [{"color":"green","modified":"2018-01-01","created":"2019-03-31","name":"kale"},{"name":"cauliflower","created":"2019-01-02"}]                             |  |  |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+--+
```

AFTER

```
+-----------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+--+
| Category1 | Count_Items | Item_Details                                                                     |  |  |
+===========+=============+==================================================================================+==+==+
| Fruit     | 1           | [{"name":"bananas","created":"2018-08-20"}]                                      |  |  |
| Vegetable | 1           | [{"color":"green","modified":"2018-01-01","created":"2019-03-31","name":"kale"}] |  |  |
+-----------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+--+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use array [`filter`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#filter) -- you have `array(map)` and want to have `array(map)`. For this, you need to construct the filter function for the `filter` (a lambda).

(Let me know if you need more detailed instructions.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the assistance, Piotr! I was able to successfully use:

`FILTER(Item_Details, x -> MIN(x['created'], x['modified']) < '2019-01-01')`

How would you recommend using the map_entries() and any_match() functions? I looked at the presto documentation for them but had a hard time figuring out how to use them properly.

Comment: @jencodes sorry, i think i musunderstood the question a bit. What you have is great!